# Como recorrer los items de un RecyclerView

Tags: android

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion donde utilizo un `RecyclerView` para mostrar una lista de elementos. Cada `item` de esta lista se encuentra personalizado, compuesto por un `textview` un `spinner` y un `editText`. La finalidad esta en actualizar los datos de los elementos de esa lista en mi base de datos. El problema se situa en que cuando me pongo a recorrer la lista e intento actualizar dichos datos me toma la actualizacion del ultimo iten modificado, osea lo seleccionado en mi `spinner` y `editText` en los demas items. A ver si alguien puede ayudarme.

ConfiguracionObraSocial.java

```
public class ConfiguracionOS extends AppCompatActivity {

BaseDeDatos db;
RecyclerView osView;
LinearLayout cancelar, actualizar;
int contador;
Context context;
String nombre, est, cos;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_configuracion_os);
    context = ConfiguracionOS.this;

    db = new BaseDeDatos(context,null,null,1);
    osView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.configuracionOS);
    osView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    osView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    ControladorObraSocial controlador = new ControladorObraSocial(context);
    final ConfiguracionOSAdapter adapter = new ConfiguracionOSAdapter(context, controlador.listaObraSocial());
    osView.setAdapter(adapter);


    cancelar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btnVolverGestionarOS);
    actualizar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btnActualizarEstadoOS);
    cancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
        }
        });

    actualizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ControladorObraSocial controlador = new ControladorObraSocial(context);

            contador = osView.getAdapter().getItemCount();

            for (int i=0; i < contador; i++ ) {
            nombre = adapter.nombre;
            cos = adapter.coseguro;
            est = adapter.estado;
            controlador.setDatos(nombre, est, cos);
            controlador.cargarDatos();
           }
           finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

ControladorOS.java

```
public class ControladorObraSocial {

Context context;
public String est, cos, nom;


public ControladorObraSocial(Context c) {
    this.context = c;
}
 public void cargarDatos(){
    BaseDeDatos conn = new BaseDeDatos(context,null,null,1);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Tablas.COLUMNA_ESTADO_OS, est);
    values.put(Tablas.COLUMNA_COSEGURO_OS, cos);
    SQLiteDatabase bd = conn.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] parametro = {nom};
    bd.update(Tablas.TABLA_OS, values, Tablas.COLUMNA_NOMBRE_OS + "= ?", parametro);
    bd.close();

}

public void setDatos(String nombre, String estado, String coseguro){
   nom = nombre;
   est = estado;
   cos = coseguro;

}
```

ConfiguracionOSAdapter.java

```
public class ConfiguracionOSAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ConfiguracionOSHolder> implements Filterable {

Context c;
public ArrayList<ObraSocial> OS, listaFiltrada;
FiltroConfiguracionOS filtro;
public String  coseguro, estado, nombre;



public ConfiguracionOSAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<ObraSocial> OS){
    this.c=ctx;
    this.OS=OS;
    this.listaFiltrada=OS;


}


@Override
public ConfiguracionOSHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_configuracion_os,null);

    //HOLDER
    ConfiguracionOSHolder holder=new ConfiguracionOSHolder(v);
    return holder;


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ConfiguracionOSHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.nombreOS.setText(OS.get(position).getNombre());
    holder.estado.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            estado = holder.estado.getSelectedItem().toString();
            nombre = holder.nombreOS.getText().toString();


            if (position == 1) {
                holder.coseguroOS.setEnabled(true);


            }else {
                holder.coseguroOS.setText("");
                holder.coseguroOS.setEnabled(false);

            }
            }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

    holder.coseguroOS.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            coseguro = holder.coseguroOS.getText().toString();

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
        }
    });
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return OS.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (filtro==null){
        filtro = new FiltroConfiguracionOS(listaFiltrada, this);
    }
    return filtro;
}

}
```

ConfiguracionOSHolder

```
public class ConfiguracionOSHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


public TextView nombreOS;
public Spinner estado;
public EditText coseguroOS;


public ConfiguracionOSHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    this.nombreOS = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.NombreOS);
    this.estado = (Spinner) itemView.findViewById(R.id.spEstadosOS);
    this.coseguroOS = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CoseguroOS);




}
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A ver si entendí, quieres almacenar en la base de datos todos los datos de los items que selecciones?

Comment: Tengo una lista de obas sociales, las mismas tienen como atributos un estado y un costo, los cuales quiero q pueda ir modificandose, ejemplo un mes la obra social se encuentre al dia, otro mes atrasada y esos cambios son los q quiero poder ir actualizando en mi base de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en que estas almacenado los valores de los **items** seleccionados en **variables** (`coseguro`, `estado` y `nombre`) y cada vez que seleccionas un nuevo item el valor de esa variable se actualiza. Por lo que en el `for` lo que haces es obtener el mismo valor de las mismas variables varias veces, lo que da la ilusión de solo obtienes el valor del ultimo item, ya que el ultimo valor que le asignas a las variables es el del ultimo item. Por lo que en tu base de datos estas actualizando el mismo valor varias veces. Es algo que lo puedes comprobar fácilmente si en el `for` imprimes el valor de las variables con la sentencia `Log.i()`.

Para solucionar tu problema debes almacenar los valores de las variables en una **lista** y después en el `for` recorres la lista y obtiene los diferentes valores que esta contiene, y procedes a almacenarlos en tu base de datos.

#### ConfiguracionOSAdapter

```
public class ConfiguracionOSAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ConfiguracionOSHolder> implements Filterable {

    ...

    public List<String> coseguro = new ArrayList<>(); 
    public List<String> estado = new ArrayList<>(); 
    public List<String> nombre = new ArrayList<>();

    ...

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ConfiguracionOSHolder holder, int position) {

        final int posicionPadre = position;

        holder.nombreOS.setText(OS.get(position).getNombre());
        holder.estado.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // Si a a lista no se ha añadido ningún elemento, el método
                // remove() lanzara una exepcion y se saltara al catch, donde
                // se añadirán los primeros elementos a lista. Si a la lista
                // ya se le había agregado un elemento, se removerá el elemento
                // con el método remove() y se agregara uno nuevo en su posición. 
                try {
                    estado.remove(posicionPadre);
                    nombre.remove(posicisionPadre);
                    estado.add(posicionPadre, holder.estado.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    nombre.add(posicionPadre, holder.nombreOS.getText().toString());
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException i) {
                    estado.add(posicionPadre, holder.estado.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    nombre.add(posicionPadre, holder.nombreOS.getText().toString());
                }

                if (position == 1) {
                    holder.coseguroOS.setEnabled(true);

                }else {
                    holder.coseguroOS.setText("");
                    holder.coseguroOS.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            ...
        });

        holder.coseguroOS.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                try {
                    coseguro.remove(posicionPadre);
                    coseguro.add(posicionPadre, holder.coseguroOS.getText().toString());
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException i) {
                    coseguro.add(posicionPadre, holder.coseguroOS.getText().toString());
                }
            }

            ...
        });
    }

    ...
}
```

En tu **actividad** obtienes los valores de las listas y los almacenas en tu base de datos. Pero en vez de recorrer las listas con el numero de items total del `recyclerView`, es mejor que lo hagas con el numero de elementos de una de las listas, ya que el numero de elementos de las lista puede ser menor al numero de items del recyclerView. Eso te ahorrara algunos errores.

#### ConfiguracionOS

```
public class ConfiguracionOS extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    String nombre, est, cos;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...

        actualizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ControladorObraSocial controlador = new ControladorObraSocial(context);

                // Obtienes el tamaño de la lista nombre. Este es el valor 
                // que utilizaras para recorrer todas las listas
                contador = osView.getAdapter().nombre.size();

                // Obtienes los valores de las listas y los almacenas en 
                // base de datos.
                for (int i=0; i < contador; i++ ) {
                nombre = adapter.nombre.get(i);
                cos = adapter.coseguro.get(i);
                est = adapter.estado.get(i);
                controlador.setDatos(nombre, est, cos);
                controlador.cargarDatos();
               }
               finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69529/discussion-on-answer-by-david-como-recorrer-los-items-de-un-recyclerview).